# Problemas realizando un scroll infinito con AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

Estoy intentando hacer funcionar un scroll infinito para una sección de noticias. Lo que quiero es que al llegar a cierto punto del scroll se me añada otro bloque de noticias, si el usuario llega al final del scroll se vuelva a añadir otro. Así hasta que ya no haya más noticias que mostrar.

Uso el siguiente `<script>`:

```
<script language="JavaScript">

var paginacion = 2
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
    console.log(scrollY);
    var altura_header = $("header").height();
    var altura_bloque_anuncio = $("#anuncio_primero_home").height();
    var altura_div_noticias = $(".cont-princ").height();
    var altura_limite = altura_header + altura_bloque_anuncio + altura_div_noticias;
    //OJO PORQUE NO SÉ SI FUNCIONA CON LA RESOLUCIÓN DE PANTALLA, IGUAL HABRÍA QUE SACAR LA ALTURA DE SU NAVEGADOR
    var altura_pantalla_usuario = screen.height;
    var altura_nagegador = $(window).height();
    var altura_nagegador_2 = $(document).height()


    console.log(this.scrollY + altura_pantalla_usuario);
    //tendrá que buscar si hay más noticias cuando lo que baje en pixeles el usuario con el scroll, más la altura de su pantalla, supere el la variable altura_limite

    if (this.scrollY + altura_pantalla_usuario >= altura_limite){
        $.ajax ({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '<?php echo $ruta ?>proces_noticias.php',
          data: { "paginacion": paginacion},
          success:function(datos){
            $("#mas_noticias").html(datos);
          }
        });

        paginacion = paginacion + 1;
    }
    console.log("Esto es paginacion:" + paginacion )
    console.log("Esto es la altura limite:" + altura_limite ) 

}, false);

</script>
```

Y muestro los datos en un div que de un inicio está vacío:

```
<div id="mas_noticias" style="width:100%;">

</div>
```

Al cargar la página y hacer scroll hacia abajo funciona bien, se me carga otro bloque de noticias, justo las siguientes, pero si sigo haciendo scroll, no se me carga otro bloque nuevo a continuación, se me actualiza el div anterior con las noticias.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que en vez de actualizarme el div donde se muestran por AJAX los resultados se me añada otro? ¿Debería usar mejor un `class` en vez de un `id` por eso de que los id no se pueden repetir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

prueba en lugar de `$("#mas_noticias").html(datos);` utilizar `$("#mas_noticias").append(datos);`

[jQuery Add Elements](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_add.asp)

Suponiendo que el div donde están las noticias se llame "div_noticias" también lo podrías hacer de la siguiente forma (si el scroll está en el div):

```js
<script language="JavaScript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
  
    var paginacion = 2

    $('#div_noticias').bind('scroll', function() {
      if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= this.scrollHeight) {
      
        $.ajax ({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '<?php echo $ruta ?>proces_noticias.php',
          data: { "paginacion": paginacion},
          success:function(datos){
          
            $("#div_noticias").append(datos);
            
          }
        });
        
        paginacion = paginacion + 1;
        
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

[jQuery scrollTop() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/css_scrolltop.asp)

[jQuery innerHeight() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_innerheight.asp)

[HTML DOM scrollHeight Property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_scrollheight.asp)

Si el scroll está en la página:

```js
<script language="JavaScript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
  
    var paginacion = 2

    $(document).bind('scroll', function() {
      if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).innerHeight() >= $(document).height()) {
      
        $.ajax ({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '<?php echo $ruta ?>proces_noticias.php',
          data: { "paginacion": paginacion},
          success:function(datos){
          
            $("#div_noticias").append(datos);
            
          }
        });
        
        paginacion = paginacion + 1;
        
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Gracias, algo ha cambiado. El problema que le veo es que me carga todos los bloques de golpe al hacer scroll.

Comment: Es realmente necesario que se carguen los bloques al llegar a cierta parte del scroll y luego al final? No puede ser solamente al llegar al final?

Comment: Bueno esa parte cierta del scroll en realidad pretende ser el final, pero lo hago con cálculos. No sé si habrá otra forma más sencilla de hacerlo.

Comment: Edito la respuesta, agrego la forma como lo hago en un proyecto mío, siempre que llega al final del div hace una nueva solicitud y carga los datos al final.

Comment: Lo he probado aunque no me funciona. No carga nada vaya aunque llegue al final del scroll.

Comment: Creo que entendí mal, el scroll al que haces referencia es el de la página y no del div, cierto?

Comment: Sí, digamos que lo que quiero es que funcione para cualquier resolución, por eso no miro el div de las noticias, sino el viewport creo que se llama.

Comment: Efectivamente lo había entendido mal, estaba trabajando sobre el div cuando en realidad debería trabajar sobre el documento, actualice nuevamente, creo que ahora sí debería funcionar.

Comment: tampoco me ha funcionado. Pero bueno valido tu respuesta porque lo que me ha servido es el .append.