# Problema al realizar un scroll infinito

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

Llevo días intentando hacer un scroll infinito que vaya cargando un código HTML y PHP según deslices, pero no hay manera. Mire tutoriales de YouTube, busque códigos de scroll infinito en Google, conseguí uno propio que funcionaba pero no cargaba lo que quería, un código HTML y PHP, pregunte y me dijeron que necesitaba ajax, trate de realizarlo con ajax, me informe.... y nada. ¿Alguien me podría dar algún consejo, algún enlace donde expliquen bien como hacer uno bien, pasarme el código....? Cualquier cosa me vale. Gracias de antemano.

Por si necesitan el código que quiero que se vaya cargando:

```
<div class= "articulo" id="articulo"> 
<article> 
<?php $sql="SELECT*FROM publicaciones 
        ORDER BY RAND() limit 1"; $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql); 
        while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){  $publicacion=$mostrar
        ['publicacion']; ?> <?php } ?>
 <hgroup> <div id="user" 
        onclick="location.href='Perfil.php'"><img src="Imagenes/Foto de perfil - copia.png" 
        id="fotouser"> <h1 id="nombreuser"> 
<?php $sql="SELECT*FROM publicaciones WHERE publicacion= ".$publicacion."' ORDER BY RAND() limit 1"; $result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql); while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){  $autor= ucfirst($mostrar ['nombre']);?> 
<?php echo $autor ?>
 <?php } ?> </h1></button>
 </div>
 <h1 id="Tituloarticulo">Título del primer artículo</h1> 
</hgroup>
 <time datetime="08-02-2021"> 
        Publicado el 08-02-2021</time> <table> 
<?php $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql); 
while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){  ?>
 <tr> 
<td>
<?php echo $mostrar['publicacion'] ?> </td>
 </tr>
 <?php } ?>
 </table> 
<footer> 
<p>Comentarios (0) </p> 
<button id="Comentarios"></button>
 </footer> 
</article>
 </div>
```

Y aqui les dejo el primer código que he hice para el scroll( pero no funciona porque no llama a una función ajax):

```
//tiene mas contenido pero es irrelevante
<script>
    

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var count=0;

        $(document).scroll(function(){
            if($(document).scrollTop()+$(window).height()>=$(document).height())
            {

                count+=1;

                $("body").append( "//Este es el codigo que quiero que aparezca cuando deslices <?php include("includes/header3.php")?>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos4.css">
<div class= "articulo" id="articulo"> 
    <article>
     <?php $sql="SELECT*FROM publicaciones ORDER BY RAND() limit 1";
         $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
         while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
           $publicacion=$mostrar['publicacion'];
           ?>
           <?php } ?>
       <hgroup>
           <div id="user" onclick="location.href='Perfil.php'"><img src="Imagenes/Foto de perfil - copia.png" id="fotouser">
             <h1 id="nombreuser">
           <?php $sql="SELECT*FROM publicaciones WHERE publicacion= '".$publicacion."' ORDER BY RAND() limit 1";
         $result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
         while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
           $autor= ucfirst($mostrar['nombre']);?> 
         <?php echo $autor ?> 
         <?php } ?>
         </h1></button>
         </div>
         <h1 id="Tituloarticulo">Título del primer artículo</h1>
       </hgroup>
         <time datetime="08-02-2021"> Publicado el 08-02-2021</time>
         <table>
         <?php
         $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
         while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
           ?>
         <tr>
           <td><?php echo $mostrar['publicacion'] ?> </td>
         </tr> 
         <?php 
         }
         ?>
         </table>
         <footer> 
             <p>Comentarios (0)</p>
             <button id="Comentarios"></button>
         </footer>
     </article>
     </div>");
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Y aqui les dejo el segundo código que intente pero que tampoco funciona

```
//Este es el arichivo llamado Tuits.php que se supone que es el que realiza la acción
<?php 
  require_once 'database2.php';
  class Tuits extends Database{
    function _construct(){

    
  }
    function getData($section){
      $query = $this->connect()->prepare('SELECT * FROM publicaciones limit :section, 2');
      $query->execute(['section'=>$section]);
    $res = [];
    $items = [];
    $n = $query->rowCount();
    if($n){
      while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $item = Array(
          'publicacion'=>$row['publicacion'],
          'nombre'=>$row['nombre'],
        );
        array_push($items, $item);
      }
      array_push($res, Array('response'=>"200"));
      array_push($res, $items);
      array_push($res, Array('page'=>($section + $n)));
      return $res;
    }else{
      array_push($res, Array('response' => "400"));
      return $res;
    }
  }
}
?>
//Esto es el archivo database2.php
<?php
class Database{
    private $dbhost   = '127.0.0.1';
    private $dbname   = 'crapping';
    private $username = 'root';
    private $password = '';
    private $charset  = 'utf8mb4';

    function connect(){
        try{
            $conexion = "mysql:host=" . $this->dbhost . ";dbname=" . $this->dbname . ";charset=" . $this->charset;

            $options = [
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false
            ];

            $pdo = new PDO($conexion, $this->username, $this->password, $options);
            return $pdo;
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            print_r('Error de conexión: ' . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
?>
//esto es donde se supone que debe aparecer el código ( está en otra página llamada pagina2.php, he omitido todo lo anterior y lo posterior ya que es irrelevante):
          <div id="tuits"> 
          </div>
          <div id="more-tuits"> 
          </div>
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Problemas realizando un scroll infinito con AJAX](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/94820/problemas-realizando-un-scroll-infinito-con-ajax)

Comment: @kemilbeltre Creo que en principio sí. Muchísimas gracias. PD: había buscado la pregunta antes de preguntar pero no me salía nada. A pesar de ello. Gracias.